# c# Parsing strings using Expressions

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I have the following code in a Windows C# form that parses a textbox string. The typical string would look something like:

z5 100c x87.50.

Another example might be:

m5 100c vs z5 100c.

In both examples, I have various attributes that are important, "z5', "100", "c", "x", "87.50". From this string I am feeding it into various functions (these functions are less important).

I found various samples and have the below code, but when I run the code it will only parse the first found expression and not iterate through and display all found expressions. For example, "z5 100c x87.50" returns 5 and c.

The the relevant information from the string: m5 100c vs z5 100c. "m" this is a month symbol. "5" is a year. "100" is a price. "c" is a structure. "vs" is a pricing function or what calls a difference function. "z" is a month symbol. "5" is a year. "100" is a separate price. "c" is a separate structure.

Is there a better method for reading the entire string, then parsing and extracting the relevant information?

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string contract = toolStripTextBox1.ToString();
    string contractConvert = contract.ToLower();

    Regex re = new Regex("c$\\.?|p$\\.?|s$\\.?|f$\\.?|cs\\.?|ps\\.?|vs\\.?|x\\.?");
    Regex rePrice = new Regex("[0-9]{1,4}(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?");

    Match m = re.Match(contractConvert.ToString());
    Match mPrice = rePrice.Match(contract.ToString());

    if (m.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Structure: " + m.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Structure incorrect!");
    }

    if (mPrice.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Strike: " + mPrice.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Structure incorrect! Requires a strike.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need a framework (per the answer suggesting Irony), but the question is very unclear and I'm not sure I understand it. Could you please clarify if, for instance, given a sample input of "z5 100c x87.50." what components you would like to isolate. It seems like you might want to use a regex to break this up into smaller components via match groups and then you may need another regex to further break each of those components up into their respective parts, as well. I may be able to provide further guidance if you can provide clarity!

Comment: Added information on the relevant information. From the string example: m5 100c vs z5 100c. "m" this is a month symbol. "5" is a year. "100" is a price. "c" is a structure. "vs" is a pricing function or what calls a difference function. "z" is a month symbol. "5" is a year. "100" is a separate price. "c" is a separate structure.

Comment: let me know if my response helps and/or if I can clarify further

Comment: please be sure to accept an answer if you find one acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this regex would help you break up your string into the relevant components:

```
([A-Za-z]{1,}[0-9.]*|[0-9.]{1,}[A-Za-z]*)
```

Just use match collections like so:

```
  string pattern = "([A-Za-z]{1,}[0-9.]*|[0-9.]{1,}[A-Za-z]*)";
  string input = "z5 100c x87.50.";

  MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
  }
```

would give you:

```
z5
100c
x87.50.
```

and then you could further analyze as needed.

You could even do it all at once using named match groups to make your life a bit easier... something like:

```
  string pattern = "(?<price_structure>[0-9.]{1,}[c]{1,})|(?<year_month>[z]{1,}[0-9]{1,})";
  string input = "z5 100c x87.50.";

  MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

  foreach (Match match in matches)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("price-structure: " + match.Groups["price_structure"].Value);
     Console.WriteLine("year-month: " + match.Groups["year_month"].Value);
  }
```

which would give you:

price-structure:

year-month: z5

price-structure: 100c

year-month:

if you wanted to break this down even further you could do something like (note that usage of + in the below is equivalent to {1,} in above examples):

```
(?<price>[0-9.]+)(?<structure>[c]+)|(?<year>[zx]+)(?<month>[0-9.]+)
```

I am separating price/structure and year/month with the or operator | to illustrate how you can keep the groups together in case it is contextually important that, for instance, c would only mean "structure" if first preceded by a price. I have also added x to year to illustrate how you can easily add other characters to the set of viable match characters as PhatWrat points out below.

The new regex will result in:

```
z5 has 4 groups:
    (price)
    (structure)
    z (year)
    5 (month)
100c has 4 groups:
    100 (price)
    c (structure)
    (year)
    (month)
x87.50. has 4 groups:
    (price)
    (structure)
    x (year)
    87.50. (month)
```

you can try this out with this online testing site:
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would take a look at Irony, a parser which will let you create a syntax tree in few minutes (obviously, you need to add the learning curve!!).

- http://irony.codeplex.com/

You'll find good samples around the net. For example:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26975/Writing-Your-First-Domain-Specific-Language-Part

Comment: this should be a comment if you're not going to provide an example

Comment: @Martin Providing an example of Irony here wouldn't make that sense. "Do you know a better way?" => "Yes, Irony.NET". If OP is interested on another solution, a link to the project plus a CodeProject article should be enough.

Comment: I am really confused on how a question about RegEx and needing to loop resulted in an answer about using Irony. Not saying it is wrong, but wondering what I missed.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer - I will look into the example you gave. It seems the tree concept is a good solution, but with a learning curve.

Comment: @TyCobb You missed opening your mind, yes! ;) It's not a question about RegExps. It's a question about asking for a better way to parse these strings!! And instead of trying to parse a string using regexps, I find better to use Irony (or other parsers) because you'll get a more solid result in less code lines and it will be easier to extend. Why not?

Comment: @JAS It has some learning curve, but if you take a sample, you'll find that 4-5 lines may do the trick. I believe it'll be easier to work with regexps. IMHO.

Comment: Touché. I am thinking I was misunderstanding what Irony can do / does do. I will have to research this.

Comment: @TyCobb Good news. I used Irony a year ago or so and after understanding its API I was able to implement a simple domain-specific command line parser. It's a very useful project.

Comment: @Martin Really? No. I'm just throwing here something I found VERY useful.

Comment: @Martin I'll need to get depressed because of I'm just sharing a possible solution!!!!!!!!! hahaha Am I in a Q&A site, or is it a "Question and Definitive Answer"? :_

Comment: I understand I get very excited about awesome libraries, but I don't think it's necessary for the issue at hand and frameworks can really add a lot of unnecessary "weight" that may not benefit long term maintenance of the code if it's only to simplify a couple of lines of code at the cost of having to maintain the project if the owner stops maintaining it and a larger download size for your installer where applicable

Comment: @Martin Standard concern. AFAIK, Irony is light-weight. Imagine how sometimes "library weight" outperforms "lighty in libs, heavy in re-inventing the wheel". At the end of the day, you dislike my approach. Period. That's why you added your own answer, and that's why a site like SO exists: democracy.

Comment: :) fair enough - I did not mean to come off as argumentative

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea--you can use capture groups.  I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing it, but it would go something like this:

First, set up your captures (I've only included 3 here--you'll need to add whatever else you want to support)

```
Regex myRe = new Regex(@"m(?<month>\d+)|(?<price>\d+)c|z(?<compMonth>\d+)");
```

Then use "Matches"

```
var myMatches = myRe.Matches(stringToSearch);
```

Finally (and I think this could probably be refactored, for those who are better at regex than I am) go through your matches and look for your groups:

```
foreach (var v in myMatches)
{
    Match myMatch = v as Match;
    if (myMatch == null)
        continue;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myMatch.Groups["month"].Value))
        MessageBox.Show("Month = " + myMatch.Groups["month"].Value);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myMatch.Groups["price"].Value))
        MessageBox.Show("Price = " + myMatch.Groups["price"].Value);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myMatch.Groups["compMonth"].Value))
        MessageBox.Show("Other Month = " + myMatch.Groups["compMonth"].Value);
}
```

For input "m5 100c vs z5 100c." your output would be:

Month = 5
Price = 100
Other Month = 5
Price = 100

By the way, I suggest [this cheat sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) and [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) as useful RegEx resources.

Comment: One issue I am noticing is the fact the Regex is a static format. For example m(?<month>\d+). That is only "m". But if someone references another month type, this will not work.

Comment: Correct--this DOES make some assumptions that may or may not hold in your project.  Note that I have `z(?<compMonth>\d+)` for the month you are comparing against (as I understood it, anyway).  If you wanted to combine them, you may be able to do something like `[mz](?<month>\d+)` You can also add things like word boundaries (`\w`), look aheads (`(?=m)`), and/or a plethora of other restrictions, as needed. Obviously, in order for this to work, you would need to know exactly what you are looking for and have a pretty good idea of the search space.

Comment: gave this an upvote since I think you got the match groups part submitted just seconds before I submitted an edit with info on how to use match groups and also for reminding me I could use the cleaner + syntax :)